# npm error while deploying on aws Elastic Beanstalk from github with CodePipeline

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, sharp

I'm trying to deploy a node.js web app on Elastic Beanstalk but I'm getting the following error on logs

````
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sharp: Are you trying to install as a root or sudo user? Try again with the --unsafe-perm flag
npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-04T08_56_56_876Z-debug-0.log

2022/06/04 08:57:03.585333 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/app/staging/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sharp: Are you trying to install as a root or sudo user? Try again with the --unsafe-perm flag
npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-04T08_56_56_876Z-debug-0.log ```
````